# Can all questions asking about the Queen's decision-making be closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

There's a lot of questions on Politics.SE asking if the queen has any decision-making power:

[Did the supreme court overrule the monarch?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/did-the-supreme-court-overrule-the-monarch)

[Can the Queen of the United Kingdom appoint her successor?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/can-the-queen-of-the-united-kingdom-appoint-her-successor)

[Could the Queen overturn the UK Supreme Court ruling regarding prorogation of Parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/45914/could-the-queen-overturn-the-uk-supreme-court-ruling-regarding-prorogation-of-pa)

[What governmental power does the Monarch hold in Great Britain?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/what-governmental-power-does-the-monarch-hold-in-great-britain)

[The actual purview of Her Majesty The Queen's prerogative?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43513/the-actual-purview-of-her-majesty-the-queens-prerogative)

[Did the supreme court overrule the monarch?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/did-the-supreme-court-overrule-the-monarch)

[Can the Queen refuse to suspend the Parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44036/can-the-queen-refuse-to-suspend-the-parliament?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Could the Queen have stopped Brexit?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20334/could-the-queen-have-stopped-brexit)

[Can the Queen still cancel Brexit?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39911/can-the-queen-still-cancel-brexit?r=SearchResults)

[What power does the Queen have in the event of a Hung Parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19716/what-power-does-the-queen-have-in-the-event-of-a-hung-parliament)

[If the elected UK parliament falls into disarray, can the reigning monarch take over?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37543/if-the-elected-uk-parliament-falls-into-disarray-can-the-reigning-monarch-take)

[What kind of legislative power does the British monarchy possess?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/what-kind-of-legislative-power-does-the-british-monarchy-possess)

[Why don't British kings and queens veto laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/174/19301)

All of them could be closed as duplicates of a single canonical question explaining that the Queen has no personal decision-making authority. Does Meta agree? If so, should we create a new canonical question or reuse an existing one?

Comment: I also think that that this makes sense, as a couple different questions.  Maybe questions on: what powers she has in regards to law/general executive power/decision making; in regards to parliament itself (and disputes there); maybe one on "extraordinary" circumstances (which would include the Brexit ones); and then anything that doesn't fit in those buckets (like the supreme court ones).

Comment: @Bobson done: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46210/what-personal-decision-making-powers-does-the-british-monarch-retain-in-practice

Comment: Relevant [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: ironically this duplicates list has a duplicate inside it

Answer (score -4):

flagging questions as duplicates on that basis, is starting to look like a wiki... where you have a page dedicated to FAQing the Queen's powers, a list of them and a list of questions, I'm not sure that's what SE is for. I always thought it was for coders...

Comment: StackOverflow is for coders.  Most of the rest of the SE network is for a vast variety of topics.  And they're all supposed to be Q&A's.  That's why we have Questions and Answers.