# How to deal with a question closed as duplicate when the OP marks several old questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I have noticed this happening on several occasions. One example:

1. A user posts [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46210/what-personal-decision-making-powers-does-the-british-monarch-retain-in-practice) which is marked as duplicate [two days later](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/46210/revisions)
2. The OP goes ahead and marks several related questions as duplicates:

[What governmental power does the Monarch hold in Great Britain in practice?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/what-governmental-power-does-the-monarch-hold-in-great-britain-in-practice)

[Can the Queen of the United Kingdom appoint her successor?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/can-the-queen-of-the-united-kingdom-appoint-her-successor)

[Why don't British kings and queens veto laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/174/why-dont-british-kings-and-queens-veto-laws)

I know that [marking older questions as duplicates of newer ones can happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question) (although it is somewhat counter-intuitive since one cannot duplicate something from the future). This is something exceptional since it is harder for the new question to gather better answers than the old one which had more time to get well developed answers.

I think the more appropriate way is to put a comment or update the original question, if it is close enough. Also, marking several older questions as duplicates (others than the duplicate cause) does not seem nice.

**Question:** How to deal with a question closed as duplicate when the OP marks several old questions as duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the author's intention was to create a dupe-target for general questions about the powers of the British monarch.

This is a good intention. When there are question which sound slightly different but always receive the same answer, then creating a new question which covers them all, posting a good answer to it, and closing all the old questions as duplicates is a good course of action.

However, the author seemed to be unaware that there already was a question which would make a perfect dupe-target for all these questions.

So what we should do is close the new question as a duplicate of the canonical question and close all the other questions as duplicates of the same question. I just did so.

Comment: OP also [asked a well-received Meta question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4052/20220) asking if he could do this, a week in advance.